# Trying to add Facebook Get Started button

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post

I am trying to add a Facebook Messenger get started button to a bot I am working on.  The API documentation says I need the following code:

```
{ 
  "get_started":{
    "payload":"<GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD>"
  }
}
```

I'm using the Chrome Postman App as I've been trying to mess around with Curl and I don't really like it.

I set up my URL as follows:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=(MY-ACCESS-TOKEN)
```

I know the access token works because I used it when setting up my bot's greeting and it worked.

Body of the request is as follows:

```
{
    "get_started":{
        "payload":"GET_STARTED"
    }
}
```

When I try to send, I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) The parameter setting_type is required",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "BC+QucQjBck"
    }
}
```

The API documentation doesn't say anything about needing to specify `"setting_type"`, nor does it say what `"setting_type"` should be.  I know that I need `"setting_type":"greeting"` for setting the greeting message.

Any suggestions?

If it's easier to make sense of what I'm doing, here is a screenshot:

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce0ji.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong endpoint.

The Getting Started button is part of Messenger Profile API, so you have to POST to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not "thread_settings"
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api#post

Comment: OK so I'm basically an idiot then! ;-)

I've changed it to messenger_profile and it seems to work now.

What is "thread_settings" used for then?

Comment: Couple of different page-related settings, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/thread_settings/